# What is need of creating test suits and test cases in soap ui.We can directly test the request.Please explain

Tags: java

I have to import one wsdl and need to create test suits for that and check that.My question why i will create test suits I can directly check the method request and get the response

Answer (score 0):

You are right with SOAP-UI you can create a request, call the service and get the response. This can be used for a simple test. 
But let's say E.g the request parameters change. You would need to create a request for each parameter that changed and send the request manually. This takes a lot of time. For that you can create testcases and test suite that sends all the request.
Or maybe you want to do a load test on the service. So you want to send several requests in a short time and check if the performance is fine. For that you can also use a testsuit. That's a lot easier than sending the requests manuall